# jQuery Sparklines: $.getJSON data can't be read

Tags: jquery, json, sparklines

I'm trying to generate a pie graph with Sparklines but I'm running into some trouble. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I feel it is a silly mistake.

I'm using the following code to generate a sparkline chart in the div **#traffic_bos_ss**:

```
//Display Visitor Screen Size Stats
$.getJSON('models/ucp/traffic/traffic_display_bos.php',
{   
    type: 'ss',
    server: server,
    api: api,
    ip: ip,
},
function(data)
{
    var values = data.views;
    //alert(values); 


    $('#traffic_bos_ss').sparkline(values,
    {
        type: "pie",
        height: "100%",
        tooltipFormat: 'data.screen - {{value}}',

    });
});
```

The JSON string fetched:

```
{"screen":"1220x1080, 1620x1080, 1920x1080","views":"[2, 2, 61]"}
```

For some reason Sparklines does not process the variable **values**. When I alert the variable it outputs "[2, 2, 61]". Now the jQuery code does work when I replace the snippet:

```
 var values = data.views;
```

with

```
 var values = [2, 2, 61];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that your call to getJSON is returning "views" which has a single string as its value:

```
"[2, 2, 61]"
```

However, when you change the code to:

```
var values = [2, 2, 61];
```

In this case you are correctly specifying an array of three integers.

Change your method which returns the JSON so that it correctly returns and array of integers for "views" instead of a single string i.e.

```
{"screen" : "1220x1080, 1620x1080, 1920x1080", "views": [2, 2, 61] }
```

See the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/urEg9/1/).

Also you say that your call to $.getJSON is working, but the method call you have written is not normal. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for jQuery's getJSON documentation.

The following should work:

```
var values;
$.getJSON( "models/ucp/traffic/traffic_display_bos.php", function(data) {
  values = data.views;
});

$('#traffic_bos_ss').sparkline(values,
{
 type: "pie",
 height: "100%",
 tooltipFormat: 'data.screen - {{value}}'
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm now. I shall read the documentary too ;)

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help Bob.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: So the JSON is formatted correctly now, and my original code works perfectly fine. However, when I adjust my code to the proper way (like you posted above) the Sparkline graph is not generated.

Comment: It might be because I used the paramater name 'json' instead of 'data' (See documentation). Try changing that.

Comment: I used the parameter data.